# Significance of minimal degrees in Bezout identity for polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime polynomials, then there exist polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $A(x)f(x)+B(x)g(x)=1$.  Further, if $A_0(x)$ and $B_0(x)$ a solution to that equation, then we can find (all?) other solutions by taking $A_h(x)=A_0(x)+h(x)g(x)$, $B_h(x)=B_0(x)-h(x)f(x)$.  Because of this, we can always find a solution where $\deg A < \deg g$.

However, sometimes we can find a solution where the degree is MUCH smaller than this bound.  For example, if $g(x)=f(x)-1$, then we can take $A(x)=1, B(x)=-1$.

Is there any significance to the minimal degrees of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$? Or perhaps a significance to the minimal degrees being as large as possible? Or perhaps conditions that can determine the degree without explicitly computing $A(x)$ and $B(x)$? Either algebraic or geometric?

Comment: Interesting question that I don't know the answer to. The minimal degree $A(x)$ is a natural choice for the inverse of $f(x)$ modulo $g(x)$. In analogy, you can also ask your question about numbers. If $g$ is an integer modulus and $f\pmod{g}$ is relatively prime to $g$, let $A$ be the inverse modulo $g$ taken between $0$ and $g$. Is there any meaning to the magnitude of $A$?